# Composer Update Failed cannot open shared object file:

Tags: composer-php

I just run

`composer update`

but I got this

```
Failed loading ./opcache.so:  ./opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './pdo.so' - ./pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './calendar.so' - ./calendar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ctype.so' - ./ctype.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
   ... so on
```

I run `php -i` and got this

```
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
... so on
```

How do I fix it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

composer use `php.ini` in `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` looks like you uncoment `extension_dir`

just comment, and reload apache and you done it.

Answer (score 1):

Your php can not find the dlls. To solve it:

- Run `php -i` and find your `php.ini` location under `Loaded Configuration File` key.
- Search for the dll files php unable to load and find their full path
- Update the extension key in your `php.ini` to the full dll path

for example:

```
extension=<path>/php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=<path>/php_pdo_mysql.dll'
extension=<path>/php_pdo_pgsql.dll:
```

Comment: usually where is extension folder in linux?

Comment: already give full path, uncomment and restart apache but `php -i` directory extension still poin to `./`

What's wrong?

Comment: What is your OS ? dll extension is for windows only.